# Unity3d Installation issues GPG error repository not signed

Tags: apt, unity, updates, repository, gnupg

I have tried installing Unity2d/3d via the terminal in a way to become more comfortable around the usage of the terminal and have across an issue where when I try and update via the terminal it brings up and error for unity2d/3d. I have copied on what is output once I have used sudo apt update:

```
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Get:5 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease [2,739 B]
Err:5 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BE3E6EA534E8243F
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BE3E6EA534E8243F
E: The repository 'https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I was using seeing the history on my terminal in the hope that I can see if I have inputted an incorrect command, although i do not see anything wrong I have noticed that I did use the same command twice, would this be reason on why I am getting the above error code?

I am using   Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64-bit  3.36.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) . Run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BE3E6EA534E8243F` .

Comment: thank you for replying to me, I have read this followed the steps but this has not proven hepful, even going as far as liveconfig, I have followed the steps and my system itself is fully update but this issue seems to be with a repository that I have added for unity3d, for some reason it wont let me add new keys to it, for it too update.

Answer (score 12):

TL;DR

```
wget -qO - https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/keys/public | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/Unity_Technologies_ApS.gpg > /dev/null
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/Unity_Technologies_ApS.gpg] https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install unityhub
```

**Issue**

There is a bug in the "[Install the Unity Hub on Linux](https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/InstallHub.html#install-hub-linux)" section of the Unity documentation.

For step 2 where we add the Unity repository to the Apt list, the documentation states the following command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signedby=/usr/share/keyrings/Unity_Technologies_ApS.gpg] https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'
```

However, when you go to update the list of sources using `sudo apt update` you will get the following error:

```
Err:14 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BE3E6EA534E8243F
```

**Solution**

There is an error in the command. Step 2 should actually be the following: (`signedby` should actually be `signed-by`)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/Unity_Technologies_ApS.gpg] https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'
```

This will resolve the `sudo apt update` command and allow installation of the Unity Hub.

Answer (score 2):

The important bit from the Unity forums link above:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/keyring-error.1290203/

```
wget -o- https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/keys/public
 
file public
 
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./unity_keyring.gpg --import public
 
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./unity_keyring.gpg --export > ./unity-archive-keyring.gpg
 
sudo mv ./unity-archive-keyring.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
 
sudo apt update
 
sudo apt-get install unityhub
```

Answer (score 0):

Different from @gencoreoperative that change `signedby` to `signed-by` that solved this issue.

My case is inverse: using `signedby` instead of `signed-by`.

My system:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```